# Snakes and ladders, check if ever will land on last square

Tags: python, linked-list

I am implementing a snakes and ladders game in python using linked lists. The node links to the next square, and the last square linked to the first square. (circular). I also have snakes and ladders, so that each node also has a parameter called `destination`, which is `None` if it does not link anywhere, but if it does, then it contains the `address of the other node`.

Something special about my game is that I have a `fixed roll`. If my fixed roll is a `4`, I will `always move 4 nodes`. If the node I land on is connected to snake or ladder, then I will go there.

I start of at the 4th square, or the square at which my roll is at.

I need a way to check if I will ever land on the last square.

[image]

Consider 16 squares, and a roll of 2. I start at 2nd square. But there is a ladder, so I move to 11th square. Now every time I move 2 nodes. After two turns, I will move to the yellow square. Then when I move again, I will move to final square, and back to square 1 (you have to land on final square to win). But then I notice that if I keep rolling 2's, I will never land on the final square, and I need a way of detecting this.

I don't need any code, but just some suggestions of how I can detect if I will never land on the final square. Thank you

Comment: Unless your game is huge, you could just simulate it. Keep a list with already visited squares (only those that you land on after 4 moves). You ither hit the final square or you'll hit a square in your visited list in which case you know you found a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem translates to the problem of finding a cycle in your square traversal.
The overall idea goes as follows: "If I have visited the same node more than once without reaching the final square, then I will never reach it."

You can implement this, for example, by including a visited member to the square class and checking if you arrive to a square that was visited before. In that case you can stop the traversal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do reachability analysis on the graph representing moves. Here is the code
to do that

```
nodes = list(range(16))
roll = list(range(1,4))
A = list(range(16))
A[1] = 10
A[9] = 6
A[5] = 13
edges = {(i,j): A[(i+j)%16] for i in nodes for j in roll}

change = True
start = current = 0
states = set([start])
oldlen = len(states)
while change:
    current = edges[(current, 2)]
    states.add(current)
    change = (oldlen != len(states))
    oldlen = len(states) 

print(states)
```

If you have multiple possible moves from a position, change detection would be bit more complicated.